# Mapping of AspNetUsers and IdentityUser

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-identity

Can't understand how the IdentityUser is mapped to AspNetUsers like there is no
[Table] attribute above IdentityUser so how EF comes to know the table is AspNetUsers.

My Code

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity comes with some default tables like Users, Roles, Logins, etc. Those tables are defined by the classes `IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole`, `IdentiyLogin`, etc.

Your `ApplicationUser` derives from the `IdentityUser`, that's why EF knows that's the `[dbo].[AspUser]` table. All those identity classes can be extended, like you did. Just inherit them and add other properties.

Here is the [official website](https://www.asp.net/identity). There is a well documented intro video abot he ASP.NET Identity. Take a look.